# How can I create an array of ints in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

How can I convert these:

```
[172592596,93038592,154137572]
```

To look like these:

```
['172592596','93038592','154137572']
```

Comment: Are you saying you have an array of ints and want to turn it into an array of strings? Because that's what your body seems to say, but the title says the opposite of that...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to turn an array of ints into an array of strings, you can do so easily using `map` and `to_s`.

```
arr = [172592596,93038592,154137572]
arr.map {|x| x.to_s}
#=> ["172592596", "93038592", "154137572"]
```

Since this is rails, you can also do (will also work in plain ruby if the version is at least 1.8.7):

```
arr.map(&:to_s)
```

To get the same result.

Comment: How can I convert ["333","444"] to [{"id":"333","id":"444"}?

Comment: @Jonathan: `{"id":"333","id":"444"}` is a syntax error. You can't use string keys using the `:` syntax with string keys. If you change it `{"id" => "333", "id" => "444"}` it still doesn't work because you can't have duplicate keys in a hash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
b = []
a = [172592596,93038592,154137572]
a.each {|a1| b << a1.to_s}
b will return ["172592596", "93038592", "154137572"]
```

You can also use collect! same as map like @sepp2k suggested.

```
a = [172592596,93038592,154137572]
a.collect! {|x| x.to_s}
```